# Auth0 SMS based multi factor authentication (MFA) for a particular Angular application

Tags: angular, auth0, multi-factor-authentication

In a single Auth0 tenant, I have two Angular applications. I'd like to enable multi-factor authentication (MFA) in a single application.

For the first step, I have enabled Phone messages.

[image]

Then I created an action.

```
exports.onExecutePostLogin = async (event, api) => {
  if(event.client.client_id === 'LJ0a69xMbbIXrtUoGC6MGhb1IkE1') {
    api.multifactor.enable('any');
  }
};
```

Then I imported that into the login flow.

[image]

Nonetheless, MFA had an impact on both of my applications.
Where did I make a mistake?